# Incompatible dimensions in Gurobi python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to solve a linear programming problem with Gurobi, although i am running in to the problem where I have incompatible dimensions already in my first constraint. My vector *b* has a shape of (3, 1) and my decision variable *lamb_obj* has shape (3,).
Could someone help me on how to fix this dimension incompatability?

My linear programming problem is depicted in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn01v.png).

The first constraint is a vector multiplication added up by a sum of two multiplied values. My code looks like this:

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
from gurobipy import *
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math

# Parameters of the lot-sizing problem
N = 2
c = [3.901260342, 1.948694185]
t = np.array([[0, 8.40717256], [2.550951155, 0]])
dmax = 20
Gamma = 20*np.sqrt(N)

b = np.array(([20],[20],[Gamma]))
I = np.identity(2)
A = np.vstack((I, [1,1]))

model = gp.Model('RO')      # Define a model

x = model.addVars(N, lb=0, ub=20, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='x')
V = model.addVars(N, N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='v')
u = model.addVars(N, N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='u')
tau = model.addVar(name='tau')
lamb_obj = model.addMVar((N + 1,), lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='lamb_obj')
lamb_1 = model.addMVar((N, N + 1), ub=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='lamb_1')
lamb_2 = model.addMVar((N, N, N + 1), ub=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='lamb_2')

model.addConstrs(b.T @ lamb_obj + quicksum(t[(i,j)]*u[(i,j)] for i in range(N) for j in range(N)) <= tau, name='blambobj')
model.optimize()
```

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be between the (b.T@ lamb_obj) with dimension (1,) part and the quicksum(t[(i,j)]*u[(i,j)] part which should be a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered in the [Gurobi Community Forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360076160491/comments/360013971971). I copy the answer for completeness:

The MVar objects are meant to build matrix expression. The term `b^T⋅λ_obj` is in your case a simple vector times vector, i.e., just a `∑ b_i⋅λ_obj_i for i in 1..N+1`.

You can model the first constraint as

```
N = 2
t = np.array([[0, 8.40717256], [2.550951155, 0]])
Gamma = 20*np.sqrt(N)
b = [Gamma for i in range(N+1)]
model = gp.Model('RO')
u = model.addVars(N, N, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='u')
tau = model.addVar(name='tau')
lamb_obj = model.addVars(N + 1, lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='lamb_obj')
model.addConstr( quicksum( b[i]*lamb_obj[i] for i in range(N+1)) + quicksum(t[i,j]*u[i,j] for i in range(N) for j in range(N)) <= tau, name="blambobj")
model.optimize()
```

You can also keep the
`lamb_obj` variables as `MVar` and still get access to the variables as a list by using the `tolist()` function.

```
lamb_obj = model.addMVar((N + 1,), lb=0, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='lamb_obj')
lamb_obj_list = lamb_obj.tolist()
model.addConstr( quicksum( b[i]*lamb_obj_list[i] for i in range(N+1)) + quicksum(t[i,j]*u[i,j] for i in range(N) for j in range(N)) <= tau, name="blambobj")
```

You can proceed with the rest of your constraints in an analogous way.

On a side note. You can drop the `from gurobipy import GRB` line, since you import everything from the `gurobipy` module in the subsequent line by using the asterisk.